# How to integrate PlayHeaven sdk in cocos 2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I cannot find any suitable link or reply about playheaven.There is only sample project in github which did not help.

If there is some nice tutorial or video link explaining in steps how to do it.Please provide the link or help me integrate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Zachary Drake, Director of Sales Engineering at PlayHaven. Officially, PlayHaven doesn't currently support Cocos2D, so we don't have instructions on how to integrate PlayHaven into a Cocos2D game. PlayHaven may very well work with Cocos2d by simply following the iOS instructions, but we don't do QA and other testing on Cocos2d the way we do for officially supported platforms (iOS, Android, Unity iOS, Unity Andoid, Adobe AIR).

This person on the Cocos2d Forums seems to have successfully integrated PlayHaven (after ranting about it), but I have not actually performed the integration steps described and cannot vouch for them:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/96170

The iOS integration documentation is not as good as we'd like it to be, and we are in the process of revising it now.  If you email support@playhaven.com with specific iOS integration problems, we can assist you. But if a Cocos2D compatibility issue breaks the integration, unfortunately there won't be anything we can do to get around that.

Thanks for your interest in PlayHaven.

Comment: Hello,Thanks a lot for providing insight on this topic.
It is such a relief..Yes,i got that link but it does not seem to be working for me. 
I will try to connect on the email id you send for more help.

Answer (score 0):

My Playhavan working sample with Cocos2d :  https://www.box.com/s/lc2p8jhngn5o8hxeuw3y

Here is complete description of SDK integration:

https://github.com/playhaven/sdk-ios

Comment: I already mention that this link does not help much.If you know the steps to show ads please tell..

Comment: hmm...not only sample, in same link there is clear explanation...go down to Integration section.

Comment: That info is not good.It does not make sense to me.If you have integrated the sdk in your app earlier.please guide me..

I am not sure how to do it by the explanation.They have included readme inside sample project containing the same info

Comment: Can you guys please confirm what should i do in Helloworld class if i do all other steps correctly.It would be great help

Comment: sorry mate..I didnt try playhaven yet....but for sure that integration tutorial is good and great enough...

Comment: ok,can you try in sample cocos project.And show me steps you follow.
You might be correct but i am not able to follow or understand.It would be great favour...Also if it is not possible then it is okay..
i will accept your answer.

Comment: don't accept until you get answer...wait for few days someone else post answr..now got some work..happy coding.

Comment: @user2264930, today I made playhavan fullScreen ads in cocos2d and working great..hope u also got it working now..if not then I can send sample..:)

Comment: Hello@iPhoneProcessor
i have not been able to successfully integrate playheaven in my game.
Please send sample,so i can try it.It would be great help :)

Comment: Just to make it work better we can call  more gameoption inside our main game.Not in appdelegate as it did not worked in mine.

Comment: :) its just sample...in game I used it for game pause, game over and all....so u got working sample :)